# iOS - Navigational flow is missed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

In my application i am adding the child view controller using the following code.

```
self.onlineUserList = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OnlineUserList"];
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.onlineUserList];
self.onlineUserList.delegate = self;
navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

CGRect aRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

[navController.view setFrame:(CGRect){0, 0, aRect.size.width, aRect.size.height-47}];

[self addChildViewController:navController];
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
[self didMoveToParentViewController:navController];
```

And i am removing the child view controller using following code.

```
[_onlineUserList removeFromParentViewController];
[_onlineUserList.view removeFromSuperview];
[_onlineUserList didMoveToParentViewController:nil];
```

It is working well. But after removing the child view controller then i am not able to do any action on the parent view controller. I think i am missing some thing navigational flow. Please help me.

Comment: The type of parentViewController is UIViewController.

Comment: Two remarks: 1. You don't have to call `didMoveToParentViewController` it will be called automatically. 2. You should remove `_onlineUserList.view` from the view hierarchy before you remove `_onlineUserList` from its parent view controller. +1 If you have overwritten one of those methods, don't forget to call `super` in your implementation.

Comment: @fabe i try it but not able to resolve the issue. Means i can not able to perform any action on view controller after removing the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get all Viewcontrollers in array , check this .

If you want all view controller of navigation ,

```
NSArray *currentControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
```

if you want first pushedviewcontroller ,

```
UIViewController *firstcontroller = self.navigationController.viewControllers.firstObject;
```

if you want last object ,

```
UIViewController *Lastcontroller = self.navigationController.viewControllers.lastObject;
```

Now trace with this code , which viewcontroller you are removing .

or Another way is just give identifier of your parentviewcontroller in `didfinishlaunchwithoption` , like ,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    SlideMenu = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SlideMenu"];
```

then add method for topviewcontroller,

```
- (UIViewController *)topViewController{
    return [self topViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController *)topViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    if (rootViewController.presentedViewController == nil) {
        return rootViewController;
    }

    if ([rootViewController.presentedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
        UIViewController *lastViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];
        return [self topViewController:lastViewController];
    }

    UIViewController *presentedViewController = (UIViewController *)rootViewController.presentedViewController;
    return [self topViewController:presentedViewController];
}
```

now create one more method in your appdelegate to present your parentviewcontroller like ,

```
- (void)ShowMenu{
    [SlideMenu ShowToViewController:[self topViewController]];
}
```

and then when you remove childviewcontroller then call ,

```
[[AppDelegate mainDelegate] ShowMenu];
```

I hope this info enough to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But not get satisfied solution.

Comment: @JAGAT what you didn't understand ?

Comment: i gave you two solution .

Comment: I am adding the child view controller and also remove it but I can not able to perform any action on view controller after removing the child view controller.

Comment: Have you understand my problem?

Comment: so as i explain in answer check navigationcontroller stack which viewcontroller you removed. have you made any demo ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110295/discussion-between-jagat-and-badal-shah).

Comment: Hello @Badal Shah I need your help in one other question. Can you please help me?